# RichTextBox Reader with a Timer

Tags: vb.net

I have a Button that shows an `OpenFileDialog`, so I can pick a `.txt` file and show it in `RichTextBox1`.
I want that when I press `Go`, the text file is read line by line with 5 sec delay and show each line read in `Label4`.

I have 5 lines in `test.txt` file. Now I choose this file from my software that I'm working on and when I choose this file its place the result of my `test.txt` file into the `RichTextBox`.

I want that when I click `Go`, it reads line 1 for 5 sec and when read it, show it in `Label4`. Then, after 5 seconds, it starts reading line 2 and show it in `Label4` and so on until all lines are read.

Here is my code:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1

    <Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
    Private Shared Function InternetSetOption(ByVal hInternet As IntPtr, ByVal dwOption As Integer, ByVal lpBuffer As IntPtr, ByVal lpdwBufferLength As Integer) As Boolean
    End Function

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    End Sub

    Public Structure Struct_INTERNET_PROXY_INFO
        Public dwAccessType As Integer
        Public proxy As IntPtr
        Public proxyBypass As IntPtr
    End Structure

    Private Sub UseProxy(ByVal strProxy As String)
        Const INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY As Integer = 38
        Const INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY As Integer = 3

        Dim struct_IPI As Struct_INTERNET_PROXY_INFO

        struct_IPI.dwAccessType = INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY
        struct_IPI.proxy = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(strProxy)
        struct_IPI.proxyBypass = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("local")

        Dim intptrStruct As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(struct_IPI))

        Marshal.StructureToPtr(struct_IPI, intptrStruct, True)
        Dim iReturn As Boolean = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY, intptrStruct, System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(struct_IPI))
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        Label4.Text = (RichTextBox1.Text)
        UseProxy(Label4.Text)
        WebBrowser1.Navigate(TextBox3.Text)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        If (OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK) Then
            RichTextBox1.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Why are you showing us all this proxy code if the question is about looping through the RichTextBox Lines property with a timer?  Hint: use a timer.

Comment: The problem is that you don't have any code to do any of what you said you wanted except to load the contents of a text file into a RichTextBox. Please edit your question to show the code that attempts to display a line every 5 seconds and remove the code that has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a Timer to your form in the designer, set the interval then handle the Timer.Tick event.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Timer1.Interval = 5000
        Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Static i As Integer
        If i < RichTextBox1.Lines.Count Then
            Label1.Text = RichTextBox1.Lines(i)
            i += 1
        Else
            Label1.Text = ""
            Timer1.Stop()
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That is working perfectly,
but now i have a new issue, before i add this code you gave it to me, IP adress on Label4 getting use for proxy
UseProxy(Label4.Text)
But now its not using it as proxy